# Import IO and got error <invalid literal for int() with base 10>

Tags: python, web-crawler, instagram

I'm using code from github for making InstagramTagCrawler
(https://github.com/karakatic/InstagramTagCrawler)

and I got an error at this part ;

```
tag = args[1]
    if len(args) > 2: 
        pages = int(args[2])
```

> invalid literal for int() with base 10:
>   'C:\Users\sec\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-3a5d58a7-5bbf-4c0d-b9a9-c699d67ae9b9.json'

My python version is 3.7.1 so I imported io instead of StringIO

May i know any fix available for this?

Comment: What are your command line arguments?

Comment: The error itself is saying whatever is in `int(args[2])` isn't a base 10 number.
But you definitely haven't provided enough information to get a helpful answer.